# A comparison of diffusions

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, stochastic-differential-equations, martingales

Consider two diffusions given by
$$X_j(t)=\int_0^t a_j(s,X_j(s))\,dW_s$$
for $j=1,2$ and $t\ge 0$, where $W_\cdot$ is a standard Wiener process/Brownian motion and the $a_j$'s are smooth enough functions such that $0\le a_1\le a_2$.

Does it then follow that $P(|X_1(1)|>x)\le P(|X_2(1)|>x)$ for all real $x$?

At least, does this comparison hold when $a_2$ is a constant?

---

There are a number of results comparing two diffusions with the same diffusion coefficients but with the drift of one of the two diffusions greater than the drift of the other one -- see e.g. [Nakao](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ojm/1200775827). However, I have been unable to find a comparison of the desired kind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inequality is not true in general — additional assumptions are needed. I think some kind of monotonicity of $a_1$ and $a_2$ should help, but this is merely a guess.

Here is a counterexample. Consider $a_2 = 1$, so that $X_2(1) = W(1)$. Let $a_1(s, x) = 1$ when $|x| < 1$ and $a_1(s, x) = 0$ otherwise. Then $X_2(1) = W(1 \wedge \tau)$, where $\tau$ is the hitting time of $\{-1, 1\}$ for $W$. It is fairly straightforward to see that if $|X_2(1)| \geqslant 1$, then $|X_1(1)| = 1$, while if $|X_2(1)| < 1$, then still $|X_1(1)| = 1$ with positive probability. Thus, the desired inequality fails to hold for $x = 1 - \epsilon$ with $\epsilon > 0$ small enough.

The question asks for smooth $a_1$ and $a_2$, so one should mollify them appropriately, but this is just a technicality, I hope the idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a comment on a related issue.

You don't have stochastic comparison of processes at a given time but you ***DO have stochastic comparison of hitting times***.

To see this, you can couple the two processes $j=1,2$ AFTER having performed the (respective) time change transformations into standard BM.

As a consequence, the two processes will have the SAME path but with different time parametizations, one FASTER than the other.

This implies stochastic comparison of hitting times.

Comment: It is not clear to me why one may expect the comparison of hitting times. Clearly one has $a_1(t,x)\le a_2(t,x)$ for all $(t,x)$, but why this implies that $a_1(t,X_1(t))\le a_2(t,X_2(t))$?

Comment: You are perfectly correct, this is not as direct as my answer misleadingly suggested. For some reason I found it quite intuitive, but one might need some form of comparison theorem for one dimensional ODE similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912468/comparison-theorem-for-ode.

Comment: The comparison should apply to $\tau_j(t)$, the time change that transform $W$ into the $X_j$'s. This should imply that $\tau_1 \leq \tau_2$, hence the comparison of hitting times.

Comment: @GJC20 I'll be delighted were you able to check that what I am suggesting is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For most comparison results, the SDEs share the same volatlity term. It is not clear to me why $a_1\le a_2$ yields larger quadratic variation. Indeed, my question is related to my post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416766/uniqueness-of-the-solution-to-some-sde-of-state-dependent-coefficient

Comment: I am suggesting writing $X^j_t = W_{\tau^j(t)}$ which requires some form of strong uniqueness. Apparently in your problem strong uniqueness is the desired conlusion. This might explain the misunderstanding.

Comment: In the initial question of Pinelis, the context was of strongly well-posed SDEs.

Comment: With the time-change argument, why $\tau^1(t)=\int_0^t a_1(s,X_1(s))^2ds \le \int_0^t a_2(s,X_2(s))^2ds=\tau^2(t)$? I don't see why the result for ODE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912468/comparison-theorem-for-ode can be adapted here. Do you mind to give a proof? Many thanks

Comment: Yes sorry, I am writing it down and I guess I rather wanted to apply this to the inverse function of $t \mapsto \tau(t)$, call it $T^i$ defined by $\tau^i \circ T^i = \mathrm{id}$. It seems to me that $$ d T^i(\tau) = a_i(T^i(\tau),W_\tau)^{-2} d \tau$$ where $\tau$ is new time parameter. Then you can apply the Gronwall-like comparison if moreover $a_i$ is Lipschitz in first variable.

Comment: $a_i$ may also be bounded from below, apparently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, while the definitions are still not clear. If my understanding is correct, here $\tau^i(t):=\langle X_i\rangle_t=\int_0^t a_i(s,X_i(s))^2ds$ and $T^{i}:=(\tau^i)^{-1}$. Correct? If so, one has $d\tau^i(t)= a_i(s,X_i(t))^2dt$. How could we achieve the above equation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134504/discussion-between-mathias-rousset-and-gjc20).