# A variant of Dubins–Schwarz's theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $W$ be a Brownian motion and $\alpha$, $\beta$ be two progressively measurable processes taking values in $\mathbb R_+$ s.t. $\alpha_t\le \beta_t$ for all $t\ge 0$. Define respectively $X$, $Y$ by

$$X_t:=\int_0^t \alpha_s dW_s,\quad Y_t:=\int_0^t \beta_s dW_s,\quad \forall t\ge 0.$$

Can we find a probability space on which one has a Brownian motion $B$ and two stochastic processes $\tau, \sigma$ s.t. $0\le\tau_t\le \sigma_t$ for all $t\ge 0$ and

$$\DeclareMathOperator\Law{Law}\Law(X)=\Law\bigl(B_{\tau}:=(B_{\tau_t})_{t\ge 0}\bigr),\quad\Law(Y)=\Law\bigl(B_{\sigma}:=(B_{\sigma_t})_{t\ge 0}\bigr)?$$

PS : Here we may assume any integrability conditions for $\alpha$, $\beta$ if needed.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes. I think "taking values in $\mathbb R_+$" means that $\alpha_t\ge 0$ (if my English is not that bad :))

Comment: In the DS theorem, the two Brownian motions constructed are adapted to different filtrations.

Comment: If there was a common Brownian motion, it would be need to be adaptable to two different filtrations and thus, for example, contradict the Markov property.

Comment: You can do this up to any finite time T, but it is a cheat.  Just imbed the first process, the wait for the brown Ian motion to return to zero, and imbed the second, even using a different Brownian motion if you like.  Of course, you could them in either order.

Comment: @mike Thank you mike for the answer, while it is not completely clear to me. Do you mind detailing this embedding procedure by providing an answer? I do appreciate

Comment: I really think you don't want this answer.  Thie biggest thing wrong with it is that it  ignores the joint distribution of the 2 processes, and while your question does not ask for the same joint distribution, I think you must want it.   Consider the case of $\alpha, \beta$ 2 different constants, so $X,Y$ are just $\alpha W_t, \beta W_t$.  What do you want done with them ?

Comment: @mike Fortunately I don't care about the joint law of $(X,Y)$. I only need that, after changing a suitable probability space, $Y$ is "later" than $X$. The motivation is that I wish to show the exit time of $(-1,1)$ for $X$ is "smaller" than that of $Y$. So I do want this answer, but I don't quit follow your construction...

Comment: that is a more doable question and you don't need a common Brownian motion for that. See second answer there: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405610/a-comparison-of-diffusions/408756#408756

Comment: If your setting is more tricky or different, I would suggest making a new question about this.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thanks. The answer seems to be highly relevant to my question, while the reasoning is not 100% clear to me...

Comment: then i suggest making a new question and we will try to help.